# I am unable to reset password instructions on my ruby on rails web application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems

I am almost done with a Ruby web application which is a forum. I have only one trouble: When a user is sent reset password instructions and clicks on "forgot my password", I see this error:

```
Showing C:/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.4.1/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb where line #5 raised:

Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to specify your `host` in your environments. 
So, say in your `production.rb` file, you would need something like this:

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: www.yourhostname.com }`

and in `development.rb`, something like this:

`config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: "dev.yourhostname.com" }`

and so on for for your test environment.

Some info from the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views).

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is:

> Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true

In `config.action_mailer.default_url_options`, you need to set a `:host` parameter, so the server knows how to link back to itself.  The server doesn't know its domain name or IP address to use.

So in your `config/production.rb` try setting something like this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'www.example.com' }
```